# What is the stroke order of the katakana ヒ?

Tags: katakana

There are 2 strokes. Let's call the short horizontal stroke A and the vertical-curving-to-horizontal stroke B.

Some sources suggest the stroke order AB while other sources suggest BA.

The katakana ヒ comes from the character 世 which when considering the relevant strokes follows the order AB.

Is there an official order of the katakana strokes available somewhere ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically, it is not a matter of AB vs. BA (the correct order is AB), but a matter of *which direction* is the A stroke written; is it left-to-right, or right-to-left?

There are numerous sources that claim it should be left-to-right.

From [kakijun.jp](https://kakijun.jp/etc/k5i.html):

[image: https://kakijun.jp/gif-h-k-al/k5i.gif]

However, there are other sources that claim it should be from right-to-left; like a more (but not completely) horizontal katakana ノ.

Also from [kakijun.jp](https://kakijun.jp/etc/k5i.html):

[image: https://kakijun.jp/gif/saji02200.gif]

[This page](https://cumacuma.jp/eq/eq_index/hi-kakijun/) explains more about each of these two theories, and a "conclusion".  It's all in Japanese, so for those who can't read it all, here's the gist of it:

1. The left-to-right direction originated with textbook publishers.  Before 1992 (平成4), they were split on the direction of the stroke.  Then in 2005 (平成17), they settled on the left-to-right direction.  This is the direction that is taught in elementary schools.
2. The right-to-left direction is due to the fact that the katakana ヒ is derived from the **right side** of the kanji **比** (not sure where you saw that it is derived from 世), where the stroke order of the A on the right side is written from right-to-left:

[image: https://cumacuma.jp/images/penji/diary/071004b.png]

So the "conclusion" is that *typically* you write it left-to-right for 硬筆 (writing w/ a pen or pencil), and right-to-left for calligraphy (書道).  But it's OK to do whichever is more natural or comfortable for you.  I guess you could say that of kana/kanji in general, but even if you're a purist, this character is still ambiguous.

I personally do it from right-to-left like a flatter ノ, but that may be because it feels more natural to me as a lefty.